# How to make aggregation in subdocuments in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have the followings mongoose schemas

Question Schema:

```
var Question = new Schema({
  title: String,
  content: String,
  createdBy: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true
  },
  answers: {
    type: [ { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Answer' } ]
  }
});
```

And Answer Schema:

```
var Answer = new Schema({
  content:String,
  createdBy: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  },
  isBest: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  createdAt: Date,
  votes: Numer    
  });
```

There's any way I can know if any  *answer* of the answers array in a single *question* has already the `isBest` property as `true` from the **Question Schema** with an aggregate. 
I've tried doing an aggregate with `$match` and `$lookup` but not results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `$unwind` your array before `$lookup`, then `$match` your `isBest` field and `$group` by `_id` to get unique questions `_id`

mongodb query is :

```
db.questions.aggregate([{
    $unwind: "$answers.type"
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: "answers",
        localField: "answers.type",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "answer"
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        "answer.isBest": true
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id"
    }
}])
```

With mongoose :

```
QuestionModel.aggregate([{
    $unwind: "$answers.type"
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: "answers",
        localField: "answers.type",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "answer"
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        "answer.isBest": true
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id"
    }
}], function(err, res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

If you want to filter your result on some specific conditions in `Questions` collection, do it before `$unwind` because `$unwind` on the whole collection can be pretty intensive